# Can I put a JMapFrame In my main JFrame?

Tags: geotools

I use Geotools, I have a main Jframe and i want to put in it a map content(JMapFrame). Is there a way to add JMapFrame in JFrame?

Comment: I come across the same question,how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a MapPane in your JFrame, JMapFrame is just a demo/debug tool.

Comment: Thank you, I have succeeded in use MapPane in my JFrame but i have probleme with toolbar how can I add cursor button and button to identify features.I have just add zoom in and zoom out buttons.

Comment: You add them just like any other swing buttons.